# Cannot make text-decoration go away

Tags: html, css

I have a row of menu buttons. I want them to be green when they are not being interacted with and bright green when hovered upon. No underlining or blue text in any scenarios. But no matter what I do, I get blue before hovering and blue underlined when I hover. Exactly the opposite of what I want to achieve.

I've looked at this every way I can think of . I am overriding every possible attribute, but nothing sticks. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

**html**

```
<div id="menu-buttons">
    <div class="link"><a href="https://www....">btn 1</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="https://www....">btn 2</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="https://www....">btn 3</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="https://www....">btn 4</a></div>
    <div class="link"><a href="https://www....">btn 5</a></div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
#menu-buttons {display:inline-block; float:right; padding-top:30px; text-align:center;}
#menu-buttons .link:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
#menu-buttons .link:link {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
#menu-buttons .link:active {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
#menu-buttons .link {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto; 
    margin-right:20px; 
    color:#73bf00;
    background:transparent; 
    vertical-align:bottom;
    font-size:small;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a {text-decoration:none; color:#73bf00;}
a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#73bf00;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
a:visited:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
a:link, a:active {text-decoration:none;}
```

[image]

Comment: a {text-decoration:none; color:#73bf00;}
a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#73bf00;}
work for me, are you sure they don't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problems:

1- You selector is not correct change `#menu-buttons .link` to `#menu-buttons .link  a`.

2- The order of your selector is not correct.

According to [W3school](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp):

> Note: :hover MUST come after :link and :visited (if they are present)
>   in the CSS definition, in order to be effective!

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/m7g32723/2/)

Comment: @Randall Does it fix your problem?

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much!

Comment: @Randall Great. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS code is missing a "}" after **text-align:center;** at the end of the first line.

That is cancelling the rest of the code

replace it with this code

```
#menu-buttons {display:inline-block; float:right; padding-top:30px; text-align:center;} 

#menu-buttons .link:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
#menu-buttons .link:link {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
#menu-buttons .link:active {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
#menu-buttons .link {
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto; 
    margin-right:20px; 
    color:#73bf00;
    background:transparent; 
    vertical-align:bottom;
    font-size:small;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-decoration:none;
}

a {text-decoration:none; color:#73bf00;}
a:visited{text-decoration:none; color:#73bf00;}
a:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
a:visited:hover {text-decoration:none; color:#92f200;}
a:link, a:active {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: I'm sorry. I made a typo in the original post. I've edited it to match what was in my code. Sorry for your trouble. Good catch, though!